# How do I calculate an average date in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of rows with a MySQL datetime field, and I want to calculate the average date on a subset of them. SQL WHERE clauses are easy, but how does one go from a datetime column to an average date?

The field is called Created, and when I try a naive approach, I get some pretty odd results:

SELECT AVG(Date(Created)) FROM table WHERE BLAH:

```
+---------------------------+
| AVG(Date(Created))        |
+---------------------------+
|   20140599.8857143        | 
+---------------------------+
```

I'd prefer output that that returned something like `2014-05-31`, but DATE() on the results of AVG() just give me NULL. How do I get an intelligible query result out of SQL?

Comment: to get a date average, the system is going to convert it to a numeric representations (usually as jan 1 1970 + value in seconds)...so the number you are seeing there is likely something along those lines.  solution in link by Dan should work (it's mssql not mysql, but the solution should work in both)...key thing is to have a set expectation of what an 'average' date is (if I take tomorrow and yesterday, does that make today the average date between them?)

Comment: This is not a dupe of that question; I'm not trying to average for a single row, just create an average from a rowset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created))) FROM table
```

Comment: That appears to have worked! I tried normal TIMESTAMP thinking it was UNIX and it was not at all happy.